# Notepad ++ remove duplicated folded blocks not lines

Tags: notepad++

I got a file with over 119000 lines and I would like to remove the duplicated blocks not lines.

ex unfolded text:

```
[1199410]
Part=1
Mesh0=001199410
Texture0=001199410
MixTex0=0
MixOpt0=0
Asb0=5
Adb0=6
Material0=default

[2199410]
Part=1
Mesh0=002199410
Texture0=002199410
MixTex0=0
MixOpt0=0
Asb0=5
Adb0=6
Material0=default
```

and this are folded:

```
+[1199410]
+[2199410]
```

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZy0.png)

What I would like is to find all duplicated folded blocks and remove them.
Also I would like to know if I can sort them up.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: So, if a duplicated block is not folded, you do not want to remove it?

Comment: I think i did not said my intention clear :D. I will fold all and after I need something to remove the duplicated folded blocks.

Comment: What i need is to find the duplicated numbers between [] and remove the whole block.